# Using oninput event to change background body color

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm working with Javascript.

I need an input that at the same time I'm writing a color the body background change to that color. Also I need the background go white with the <kbd>delete</kbd> key.

```
<strike>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Write a color for background</p>

<input type="text" id="myInput" oninput="colorForBack()">

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function colorForBack() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Your color: " + x;
  element.style.backgroundColor = x;
 
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
</strike>
```

Comment: Why the `</strike>` as `</html>` wrapper?

Comment: no idea. Thank you!

Comment: `element` what is exactly `element`? You mean `document.body`?

Comment: yes. I was wrong. document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Don't use inline JS  `on*` attribute handlers, same as you don't use inline `style` attributes. It's hard to debug and maintain. JS should be in one place only and that's your `script`.  Use [Element.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead.
- Get the BODY Element using `document.body`  or `document.querySelector("body")`
- Listen for `"input"` and `"keyup"` Events. On `"keyup"` we can deduce the key using [KeyboardEvent.key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) - and if matches the string "Delete" you can reset your input value accordingly
- Don't insert unsanitized strings into your DOM! Use [Node.textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) when inserting a user input string value into your document.

```js
const EL_body = document.body;
const EL_input = document.querySelector("#myInput");
const EL_color = document.querySelector("#demo");

function setBodyBackground(ev) {
  const isDelete = ev?.key === "Delete";
  const color = isDelete ? "transparent" : EL_input.value;
  EL_color.textContent = `Your color: ${color}`;
  EL_body.style.backgroundColor = color;
  if (isDelete) EL_input.value = ""; // Reset input value on Delete key
}

["input", "keyup"].forEach(evName => EL_input.addEventListener(evName, setBodyBackground))
```

```html
<p>Write a color for background</p>
<input type="text" id="myInput">
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Read also:

- [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)
- [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)
- [Babel compiler](https://babeljs.io/) for your next generation JS